# Netsuite- Workflow to create support case tasks

Tags: netsuite

I want to create tasks automatically through workflow when I submit a support case.

1. When i try to associate company of a tasks with the company of support case the reference is not matching. I have followed steps

   - Company  =>  VALUE FIELD =  Company
2. Also assigned to field is always set to case submitted by, I want to set it to assigned to field of case form.

Can anyone help me in assigning a value for `"company"` and `"assigned to"` fields to tasks from case-form.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering {company} in the Formula field.

Either your method or using a formula should work. If it's not working, then there's probably a configuration causing a mismatch between the two fields.

Comment: Company field in Tasks form contains list of companies and company field in case form contains list of employees, so can not assign employee to company. I have raised a support case with netsuite but there is no response yet.